# RESTful - WCF - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I created a simple RESTful application in WCF(c#). When I'm populating using (GET) I've received this error

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

I received the error in the part of `target.DocumentLines[0].itemCode = "";`.

Here's my code:

```
        public PRRequestData[] getAllPR()
    {
        List<PRRequestData> list = new List<PRRequestData>();

        try
        {
            string sqlSelect = "SELECT DocEntry, Comments, ReqDate FROM OPRQ";
            APP.strCommand = sqlSelect;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt = APP.Ds.Tables[0];

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                // Person target = Activator.CreateInstance();
                PRRequestData target = new PRRequestData();
                target.requiredDate = row["ReqDate"].ToString();
                target.remarks = row["Comments"].ToString();
                target.docEntry = row["DocEntry"].ToString();
                // DataColumnAttribute.Bind(row,target);

                sqlSelect = "SELECT ItemCode, Quantity, Price, VendorNum, TaxCode FROM PRQ1 WHERE DocEntry = '" + row["DocEntry"].ToString() + "' ";
                APP.strCommand = sqlSelect;
                for (var i = 0; i < APP.Ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    target.DocumentLines[0].itemCode = "";

                }

                list.Add(target);
            }

            return list.ToArray();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.ToString();
        }

        return list.ToArray();
```

Here's my DataContract source code also:

```
    [DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public class PRRequestData
{
    [DataMember]
    public string docEntry { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string remarks { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string requiredDate { get; set; }

    //[DataMember]
    //public int rowcount { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public RequestDataDetails[] DocumentLines;
}

[DataContract]
public class RequestDataDetails
{
    [DataMember]
    public string itemCode { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public decimal quantity { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public decimal price { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string supplier { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string taxcode { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Looks like either target.DocumentLines[0] or target.DocumentLines are null, have you tried debugging?

Comment: Yes, already did. What I'm trying to do is set data to the DataMember of DocumentLines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're not initialising this property

```
[DataMember]
public RequestDataDetails[] DocumentLines;
```

I recommend you to use List instead of RequestDataDetails[], as anyway you'll have to use an internal list.

Initialise the List of RequestDataDetails to fill it from the query, before the for loop.

```
List<RequestDataDetails> requestDetails = new List<RequestDataDetails>
```

Then change the for loop to add to that list instead of setting an array, im using the assignment you were doing, not sure if it'll do what you expect, just tell me if it suits your needs.

```
requestDetails.add(new RequestDataDetails { itemCode = "" });
```

instead of

```
target.DocumentLines[0].itemCode = "";
```

Then after the for loop convert the list to an array and assign it to `target`

```
target.DocumentLines = requestDetails.ToArray();
```

Hope it works!